# Who is the chief engineer of the Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In *Discovery* episode 2x04, "An Obol for Charon", temporary crewmember

> Reno

describes her task as follows:

> Chief engineer sent me to firewall off the critical propulsion systems.

She tells this to Tilly and Stamets.

Who is that chief engineer? During season 1, I was convinced Stamets is the chief engineer of the ship, but the above statement makes it obvious that someone else holds that position - have we seen him or her, or has their name been mentioned so far?

Comment: "*Lt. Commander Paul Stamets is the U.S.S. Discovery’s science officer and chief engineer, and was the partner of the late Dr. Hugh Culber.*" - http://www.startrek.com/database_article/stamets

Comment: @Valorum: Based upon the quoted piece of dialogue, that is wrong.

Comment: Well, indeed...

Comment: One assumes that after he became catatonic, then mentally unstable, then decided to leave the ship, he probably was replaced as Chief Engineer.

Comment: It's open to question whether Stamets was ever really the Chief Engineer because all he ever worked on so far as we know was the magic mushroom drive.  That may have been been his place in the ship's rank heirarchy but someone else was apparently in charge of the real engines.

Comment: @DavidJohnston - His official bio on the StarTrek website says that he's Chief Engineer though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing on screen to indicate that Stamets was the chief engineer, ever. He was the spore-drive specialist, and was never seen doing anything outside of that which a chief engineer would be responsible for.

The confusion likely arose because *Discovery* was the first Star Trek series where the Chief Engineer *wasn't* one of the primary characters. Likewise, we have no idea who the Chief Medical Officer is, and before Burnham was reinstated and given the assignment, it wasn't clear who was Chief Science Officer.

Comment: Good grief! *Three* departments where we don't know who the chiefs are? I suppose that's the problem with focusing on "lower decks" crew members. If the stakes are big enough that the department chiefs would naturally get involved, their constant absence just seems ridiculous.

Comment: "There's nothing on screen to indicate that Stamets was the chief engineer, ever." - well, that's *somewhat* true as it was never spoken out literally. Yet, he was evidently in charge of main engineering - the area of the ship *and* its assigned personnel -, which somewhat insinuates he *was* the chief engineer.

Comment: @DavidJohnston: "He never appeared on screen and was given two different names." - are you talking about Discovery or about TNG in that sentence? It seems to be inaccurate in both cases (Discovery did not mention any other chief engineer so far, as far as I recall, and in TNG's first season, at least three chief engineers appeared on screen (and there is even an explicit mention of there being several chief engineers at that point)).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Stamets wasn't in charge of main engineering; he only dealt with the spore drive (which makes sense, as he was primarily a biologist). He was never shown as dealing with the warp core, warp drives, ship damage and repair, or a whole host of the other issues Chief Engineers on Starfleet ships typically are.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: Well, he invariably seems to be the highest-ranking officer we see whenever we see the Discovery's main engineering. And we've never seen Discovery's conventional warp core so far, nor heard of anyone else who would do anything particular with it. And on top of that, the very first time in the series we heard about Stamets was with the lines "You've been assigned to engineering. Lieutenant Stamets will task you with specific duties." This sounds a lot like, at least at that point in the series, Stamets was supposed to be the one running engineering. (Yes, he may of course ...

Comment: ... be leading a sub-team, but then it would be very strange IMHO to introduce him like that rather than say something explicit like "You've been assigned to the spore drive team in engineering." or, if the spore drive shouldn't be mentioned at the point yet, "You've been assigned to a special research team in engineering.") The premise may have changed since then, and I'm not saying it was ever made explicit, just that throughout season 1, everything we saw insinuated that Stamets was, in fact, the chief engineer. Which may also be the reason for the respective remark on startrek.com.

Comment: In 2016, when Rapp was cast, this is how Stamets was described: "an “astromycologist,” fungus expert, and Starfleet Science Officer aboard the Starship Discovery."

Comment: `The confusion likely arose because Discovery was the first Star Trek series where the Chief Engineer wasn't one of the primary characters.` 

TNG season 1 didn't have a consistent chief engineer :) And DS9 O'Brian was 'Chief of Operations' rather than 'Chief Engineer'.

Comment: @Thunderforge: `Good grief! Three departments where we don't know who the chiefs are?` -- which departments are you talking about, here?

Comment: @Pod Engineering, Science, and Medical, the three discussed in the answer.

Comment: O'Brien was *de facto* chief engineer, as engineering clearly fell underneath his Operations assignment. It's possible that for fixed installations Starfleet didn't use the exact same terminology as they did for equivalent positions on ships.

Comment: @Thunderforge  `Engineering, Science, and Medical`. That's what I thought... except we know who the heads are for Science (Burnham) and Medical (Dr. Culbert, then Dr. Pollard). It's probably also safe (but not confirmed) to assume that the bridge offices are the various heads, as they were in the other shows. The only one that's a mystery is Engineering.

Comment: @Pod, no, Culbert was never stated to be CMO, nor Pollard. Culbert was, indeed, explicitly pulled off a patient, which wouldn't be the case if he was CMO.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: 'this is how Stamets was described: "an “astromycologist,” fungus expert, and Starfleet Science Officer aboard the Starship Discovery."' - now, in the current episode, Stamets is being the lead designer of something invovling stasis fields and a power supply based upon a plasma reactor fed with deuterium. Looks like even the authors have forgotten he wasn't supposed to be an engineer.

Comment: I've marked this as accepted because I think what you describe was the original intention. By episode 2x13, however, I am convinced that the authors themselves are convinced Stamets is one of the highest-ranking members of Discovery's engineering staff. In a meeting, he states "I'll have our engineering teams [do something]", and a bit later, we see him supervising crewmen refitting shuttles with mission-specific (non-spore-related) equipment.